# How insert a youtube video in a WordPress plugin page?

Tags: wordpress

I have created a plugin for WordPress and I have uploaded it to the Wordpress Plugin repository.

Now, I want to show a Youtube Video in the plugin description as this one http://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-media-gallery/ (scroll down a little to see the Youtube video).

In the readme.txt, I have tried those snippets without success:

```
[iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/A3PDXmYoF5U" width="100%" height="480"] 

[embed]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3PDXmYoF5U[/embed]

[embed]
     http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3PDXmYoF5U
[/embed]

[embed]
     http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3PDXmYoF5U
[embed]
```

Is anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the Youtube link in the description and it will be automatically converted...